# 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, image

```
ProductRef.child(productRandomKey).updateChildren(productMap)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                            downloadImageUrl = task.getResult().toString();  //it is the problem

                            Intent intent = new Intent(AdminAddNewProductActivity.this, AdminCategoryActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(AdminAddNewProductActivity.this, "Product is added successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        else{

                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                            String message = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(AdminAddNewProductActivity.this, "Error: "+message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    }
                });
```

final StorageReference filePath = ProductImageRef.child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + productRandomKey + ".jpg");

```
    final UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putFile(ImageUri);
```

downloadImageUrl = filePath.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        return filePath.getDownloadUrl();

I have used these lines previously. it is occurring when I am trying to upload a picture the app crash.

Comment: your `task.getResult()` is probably null. Add check for it

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `toString();` on `null` object. So you can add some condition to check it. Change this:

```
downloadImageUrl = task.getResult().toString();
```

to

```
Result result = task.getResult();

if (result == null) {
    // TODO - handle null object here (e.g. show some placeholder)
} else {
    downloadImageUrl = result.toString();
}
```